# How to use Twig_Markup object type in an If statement

Tags: twig

I want to reuse pretty heavy logic only code a few times, in php I would use a function, but in twig I went with a solution from [this old question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/use-a-twig-macro-to-set-a-variable).

In short, I use a macro like that:

```
{% import _self as test %}

{% macro check() %}
    {{ test }}
{% endmacro %}

{% set v = test.check() %}
{% if v == 'test' %} 
    this should display 
{% endif %}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://twigfiddle.com/kyv3zr/2

The problem is that v is a Twig_markup object. It doesn't seem to have any public properties. Running dump on it gives me this:

```
object(Twig_Markup)#1244 (2) { ["content":protected]=> string(13) " 1 " ["charset":protected]=> string(5) "UTF-8" }
```

How do I use it in an if statement?

Or is there a better way of storing a logic only code for reuse across templates?

Comment: I have an important set of questions, think about them before responding: What is it you actually want to do? What is the end result you want to achieve? I see now what the macro does, but you can make it do whatever you need - and I don't understand what is the end result you need. For example, can you show resultant html code that you want to produce, or maybe a sample picture. What are your inputs, and what are your outputs.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is called `v` then the dump seems to show it has a `content` value, so try:

```
{% if v.content == '1' %}
  {# do something here #}
{% endif %}
```

not certain though, but try it.

**EDIT #2 - based on comments question.**
So I guess if you want to use `v` in an if statement, you would use it like so:

```
{% if v == '1' %}
  {# do something here #}
{% endif %}
```

This presumes it does equal to "1".

Comment: Yes, but it's protected and all I'm getting is : Neither the property "content" nor one of the methods "content()", "getcontent()"/"iscontent()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Twig_Markup"

Comment: Can you post your Doctrine Entity code? Or maybe you are not using Doctrine? Or whatever code you use to create object `v` shown in your post.

Comment: I've added some context to my question

Comment: Maybe the file `macros/_visibility.html` contains more information? Based on what you just posted, that doesn't help me.

Comment: The content of the macros/_visibility.html is irrelevant, I can remove all the content from there and simply print {{ true }}, so that value will be passed to v, now how do I use v in an if statement?

Comment: @Lukigi how are you passing your variables to the templates? Variables don't get transformed into `Twig_Markup`'s automatically. Copy and run the fiddle [here](https://twigfiddle.com/kyv3zr) and you will see output types like `int`, `string` and `array`

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear yesterday, it was a very long and frustrating night. I've simplified the code and created a fiddle. Question updated.

Comment: If you want to check the return value I'm guessing your better of with [extending twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#functions) and creating a function for this. Macro's should be used for stuff like recursion, like a menu with children