# Feed image through ACF to Twig / Timber WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

In my twig template, I have the following:

```
{% include '@hc/components/home-hero.twig' with {
    'image': '/assets/images/home-hero.png',
    'title' : 'Title goes here',
```

To feed through from ACF fields on Wordpress I do the following:

```
{% include '@hc/components/home-hero.twig' with {
    'image': Image(data.hero_image),
    'title' : data.title_field,
```

The 'title' works fine, as does any other kind of field. For some reason I cannot get images to pass through. I have tried loads of variations such as:

```
{% set header_image %}  {{ post.meta('header_image') }} {% endset %} 
{% include '@hc/components/home-hero.twig' with {
    'image': header_image,
```

When doing a dump of header_image, I get the following:

```
object(Twig\Markup)#2380 (2) {["content":protected]=>string(66) "url of image is in here" ["charset":protected]=>string(5) "UTF-8" }
```

Does anybody have a clue what is going on? It is driving me mad!

Thank you

Comment: What does `data.hero_image` return? If it is url or id, try `Image(data.hero_image).src`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [timber / acf cheatsheet](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/#image-field) your should probably use something like:

```
{% include '@hc/components/home-hero.twig' with {
        'image': Image(post.meta('header_image)),
        'title' : data.title_field
    }
%}
```

Otherwise, if you can add the code for home-hero.twig, to see how the image varibale is used/queried, see [similiar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685121/how-to-use-twig-markup-object-type-in-an-if-statement).